# Python define function to calculate workdays Input: initial date, final date and holydays that come from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, counter

I have to create a function the brings me the count of days between two dates and it must take out weekends and holidays that are inside of a dataframe.

my holidays df looks like this:

```
       Data

0   2001-01-01

1   2001-02-26

2   2001-02-27

3   2001-04-13

4   2001-04-21

df.info()

class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'

RangeIndex: 936 entries, 0 to 935

Data columns (total 1 columns):

   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype   
             
 0   Data    936 non-null    datetime64[ns]

dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)

memory usage: 7.4 KB
```

So it should look like:

```
def delta_days (date_initial, date_end, holidays)

   .....
```

What would be the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

def delta_days(date_initial, date_end, holidays):
  date_initial = datetime.strptime(date_initial,'%Y-%m-%d')
  date_end     = datetime.strptime(date_end,'%Y-%m-%d')
  work_days    = pd.bdate_range(start=date_initial, end=date_end, holidays=holidays, freq='C')
  return(len(work_days))
```

Testing the code:

```
 holidays =  ['2021-01-01','2021-04-04','2021-04-21','2021-05-01','2021-09-07','2021-10-12','2021-11-02','2021-11-15','2021-12-25']
 delta_days('2021-01-01','2021-12-31',holidays=holidays)
```

Output:

```
255
```

Now, you can go one step further and automate the construction of the holidays list:

```
from workalendar.america import Brazil

cal = Brazil()
datetime_feriados = pd.to_datetime([d[0] for d in cal.holidays(2021)])
lista_feriados    = [lista_feriados.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for lista_feriados in datetime_feriados]
```

Output:

```
lista_feriados

['2021-01-01','2021-04-04','2021-04-21','2021-05-01','2021-09-07','2021-10-12','2021-11-02','2021-11-15','2021-12-25']
```

Comment: Oh thats perfect! Thats what I have to do, but i have to take the holidays from the ANBIMA site tu use them. thanks

Comment: Glad it worked. You could automate the download of Anbima's list as well.

Comment: How would you do to take out the weekends also?

Comment: Weekends are alread wiped out in the function. Pandas method 'bdate_range' just does that. It creates a list of business dates out of a date range.